# DaggerAppComponent cannot be resolved Android

Tags: android, dagger2

Доброго времени.
Пытаюсь  прикрутить  Dagger 2

В gradle:

```
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
```

При построении  проекта  все  проходит  нормально. Но  при  инжекте  в  активити  падает  с  ошибкой в gradle

```
Error:(6, 8) The import com.hubble.news.di.DaggerAppComponent cannot be resolved
Error:(25, 16) DaggerAppComponent cannot be resolved
Error:(14, 10) com.hubble.news.di.modules.RetrofitModule cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
    com.hubble.news.di.modules.RetrofitModule is injected at
        com.hubble.news.ui.activity.MainActivity.retrofitModule
    com.hubble.news.ui.activity.MainActivity is injected at
        com.hubble.news.di.AppComponent.inject(mainActivity)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack compilation exception
D:\ProgectAndroid\Hubble\app\src\main\java\com\hubble\news\di\AppComponent.java
```

MainActivity  в  котором инжект:

```
public class MainActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    RetrofitModule retrofitModule;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        App.getComponent().inject(this);

    }
}
```

App:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static AppComponent component;

    public static AppComponent getComponent(){
        return component;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = buildComponent();
    }

    protected AppComponent buildComponent() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule())
                .build();
    }
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Component(modules = {RetrofitModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

}
```

RetrofitModule

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public HubbleApi provideRetrofit() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .serializeNulls()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://hubblesite.org/")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(HubbleApi.class);
    }
}
```

Как  это  вылечить???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инъектить надо не модуль, но зависимость, кою модуль предоставляет. Т.е. замените тип переменной в активити на HubbleApi вместо RetrofitModule